# Perfect SEO for simple website?

Tags: html, web, seo

I have a simple website with 1 Logo as Header, 3 Buttons in the middle and a footer with some Text.

Now I was wondering, what the perfect header for a website would be for it to be SEO friendly.

This is what a previous Developer did **(Replaced sensitive information with %)**:

```
<head profile="http://dublincore.org/documents/dcq-html/">
    <link rel="schema.DC" href="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/">
    <link rel="schema.DCTERMS" href="http://purl.org/dc/terms/">
    <title>% - %</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
    <meta name="keywords" content="%,%,%,...">
    <meta name="description" content="% - %">
    <meta name="author" content="%" />
    <meta name="Kategorie" content="%" />
    <meta name="DC.title" content="%" />
    <meta name="DC.creator" content="%" />
    <meta name="DC.subject" content="%" />
    <meta name="DC.description" content="%" />
    <meta name="DC.publisher" content="%" />
    <meta name="DC.contributor" content="%" />
    <meta name="DC.type" content="%" />
    <meta name="DC.format" content="text/html" scheme="DCTERMS.IMT" />
    <meta name="DC.identifier" content="%" scheme="DCTERMS.URI" />
    <meta name="DC.language" content="de" scheme="DCTERMS.RFC3066" />
    <meta name="DC.relation" content="%" />
    <meta name="DC.coverage" content="%" scheme="DCTERMS.TGN" />
    <meta name="DC.rights" content="%" />
    <meta http-equiv="expires" content="0">
    <meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache">
    <meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache">
    <meta http-equiv="content-language" content="de">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8" />
</head>
```

My Question is: How much of this is actually needed? I heard DublinCore is obsolete, and meta names aren't really taken in consideration...so what would make a perfect head tag ?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is asking for SEO advice. It might be on-topic on [webmasters.se].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most of them are not read by Google (assuming Google is the search engine in mind)

Have a read [here](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/79812?hl=en) of the Meta tags that Google does understand and you can remove the rest if you wanted.

Answer (score 0):

You should really only need keywords and Description. You should, though, also implement [Google Analytics](http://www.google.com/analytics/). Also, see this site as a reference: http://codeboxr.com/blogs/is-single-page-one-page-website-bad-for-seo.